Delphi FMX: TEdit on modal dialog created in DLL loses focus and caret
In a FireMonkey app on Windows, I have a DLL with various dialog boxes, some of which have TEdit controls.
When I launch these dialogs from the main application, the TEdit boxes do not display the caret. Tracing the problem, I see that the TEdits never receive focus, even when I set the focus programmatically. Also, if I create the dialogs in the main app without the DLL, the caret shows as it should.
Is there any way to solve this problem with the DLL and get the Edit boxes to show their caret properly? The following shows an example of my code.
example dialog:
unit dlldlg;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit;

type
  TDllForm = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DllForm: TDllForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.

library:
library BTDialog;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.UITypes,
  FMX.Forms,
  {[...]}
  dlldlg in 'dlldlg.pas' {DllForm};

{$R *.res}

var Main:TForm;

Function DLLFormDlg:boolean; stdcall;
var
  DllForm: TDllForm;
begin
  DllForm := TDllForm.Create(Application);
  result := false;
  try
    if DllForm.ShowModal = mrOK then
      result := true;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(DllForm);
  end;
end;

exports
    {[...]}
   {,} DLLFormDlg
   ;
begin
end.

MainForm:
interface

const DlgDLL = 'BTDialog.dll';

Function DLLFormDlg:boolean; stdcall;external DlgDLL;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TBTMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DLLFormDlg;
    { shows dialog box, but the TEdit component does not show its caret }
end;    



